# Jackson doesn't serialize hibernate lazy fetched field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

During the debugging i can see that required in my case field is fetched.
[image]

But after response is fetched i got this.
[image]

This is how defiend my field and getter for it.

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = PhysicianNote.PHYSICIAN, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private Set<PhysicianNote> notes;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("notes")
public List<PhysicianNote> getNotes() {
    return Hibernate.isInitialized(notes)
            ? new ArrayList<>(notes)
            : new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And this is how defined my hibernate 5 module.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addSerializer(Instant.class, new InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision());
        Hibernate5Module h5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
        h5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);
        objectMapper.registerModules(module, h5Module);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`, a field marked with `@JsonBackReference` will not be serialized, it should be on `PhysicianNote#physician` and `@JsonManagedReference` should be on `notes`.